# how to subscribe disparity image?

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have started working with stereo camera. I have the disparity image on the /stereo/disparity topic. Now I want to subcribe that stereo_msgs/DisparityImage form the /stereo/disparity topic. For subscribing this is

image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);

image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/stereo/disparity", 1, imageCallback);

enough? Or do i have to use some other transport for disparity image. .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197396/how-to-subscribe-disparity-image?/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure *image_transport* can handle *stereo_msgs/DisparityImage*, probably it can. In such case just make sure that *imageCallback* has the following signature:

```
void imageCallback(const stereo_msgs::DisparityImage& msg);
```

If that doesn't work, this will work for sure:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <stereo_msgs/DisparityImage.h>

void disparityImageCallback(const stereo_msgs::DisparityImage& msg)
{
    //Do cool stuff here
}

....

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ...
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/stereo/disparity", 1, disparityImageCallback);

  ...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-14**:
thank you very much...
it worked..

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-11-14**:
Glad I could help :)

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-14**:
well now i am stuck with the image encodings and step size.. do ypu have any idea about the format of the disparity image.. thanks in advance

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-11-16**:
Well, inside the DisparityImage structure there is a field called *image* with all the [information you need](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html). The field *image* contains a string called *enconding* and a *uint32 step* so you can figure out how to interpret the raw data

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thanks again.. the step field is visible but if I try to print the encoding it is showing an error..

error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >::_encoding_type {aka struct std::basic_string}’ through ‘...’

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-11-17**:
Remember that *encoding* is a message of type [*string*](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) and therefore to access the actual string of characters you need to reference it as *encoding.data*

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-06-28**:
Hello there,
Thanks for this answer. I know its have been a while, but, I am not sure how to handle the msg object in `disparityImageCallback`. I am trying to get the image as msg->image but is not working...

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-07-06**:
Since disparityImageCallback receives a reference to a stereo_msgs/DisparityImage, msg.image should be the way to go